# Circles in the Mail.app on the iPhone - iOS Programming

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

In the Mail application on the iPhone, when edit is tapped, small circles appear next to the cells which allow the user to tap multiple cells.

Is this a built in feature? How can I get this set up in my UITableView in my iPhone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sort of. There is an „editing mode“ for UITableViews built-in. Have a look at http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html Matt explaines it pretty well, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is not available by default in iOS 4. As ckruse mentioned there are a few guides to accomplish the look yourself. If you have a paid iOS Developer account then I suggest you look at the UITableView documentation in iOS 5 ;)